# VS error while setting up Unit Test: A reference to 'my_project' cannot be added because it is incompatible with this project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am trying to get started in unittesting in C++ using Visual Studio. I tried to follow along to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2022).

I first created a "Windows Console Application" "my_project", where I wrote some basic functions into it's main.cpp file.

[image: my_project]

Next I right-clicked into the Project Solution and added a new project ("Unit Test App") "project_to_test_myproject", in which I would test these functions:

[image: project_to_test_myproject]

When I now tried to add "my_project" to the references of "project_to_test_myproject", the following error occurred:
[image: Error message]

Can someone tell me where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

The unit test app is for UWP projects. Use Native Unit Test project instead.